# Quick audio cleanup filters in Kdenlive

Tags: audio, kdenlive

I have a project where people are talking in amateur footage. That means no lava or overhead microphone. Just digital camera. A lot of outside noise is caught.

Is there a filter, multi-band equalizer, compressor, limiter or anything I can drop on all the little fragments of audio to make the end result *somewhat* better? There are tools that might be able to do the job, but all tools come without any presets, so it's hard to figure out sensible defaults without a more technical background in audio. Furthermore, settings that depend on current levels (i.e. "attack") seem to be reset on every audio snippet and I don't believe I can let all the audio be treated as one channel.

Once the project is complete, a more dedicated audio software can be used. But it will take a while and a lot of exports will be made. I have no time to finalize the audio externally for every export. It would be nice if there was a way to improve the audio *somewhat* using clever computer wizardry.

Perhaps there is a trick, like freezing all the audio into one single clip and apply some presets on that.

Comment: Sadly, there's very little you can do about bad source audio.  As you've discovered, there are some audio processing tools that *might* help, but the specific settings depend on the echo patterns in that particular room in that particular location; hence the lack of presets.  You can get *some* improvement, but it will be very labor-intensive with lots of trial and error, and the final improvement will be relatively minor.

Answer (score 1):

Currently your best bet is to extract the audio of the clip before you start editing, and then importing it into Audacity, which has a great toolbox for dealing with outside noise.
Once done, you can export from Audacity and back into Kdenlive.

It's a workaround, and very labor intensive. It would have been much nicer to be able to apply some basic audio filters directly in Kdenlive.

Comment: [This tutorial](https://drbacchus.com/video-noise-reduction-using-kdenlive-and-audacity/) goes in the same vein, and it doesn't seem to be that much work.